# Removing non alphabetic character from string c++

Tags: c++, string, idioms

This is driving me to the wall.

```
template<typename t>
void Tree<t>::readFromFile(string filename)
{
//
    str.erase( remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), aZCheck), str.end());
//
}
template<typename t>
bool Tree<t>::aZCheck(char c)
{
    if (isalpha(c))
        return false;
    else return true;

}
```

Gives an error :`cannot convert 'Tree<t>::aZCheck<std::basic_string<char> >' from type 'bool (Tree<std::basic_string<char> >::)(char)' to type 'bool (Tree<std::basic_string<char> >::*)(char)'|`

Worked fine until I moved both methods into the class.

```
str.erase( remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isalpha), str.end());
```

Doesnt work without using static cast and I am using cctype or ctype.h libraries, static cast is for c++ locale library which I am not using.

I can get it to work using static cast, but then I cant seem to make it negative `!isalpha`.
As I need to delete non alphabetic characters and as it is , it will delete alphabetic ones. Forcing me into creating separate method, which I mentioned as my first issue. And it worked until I moved method into class.

Chances are I am missing something completely obvious, but I just cant figure it out...

Comment: good read [link](http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/function.html)

Comment: @40two The FQA hasn't been updated for C++11, I see. An updated answer to 33.10 that uses C++11's lambdas could be relevant here, if it wouldn't be possible to update `aZCheck` to be static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare the function as a static member function

```
static bool aZCheck(char c);
```

Take into account that the function could be defined simpler

```
template<typename t>
inline bool Tree<t>::aZCheck( char c )
{
    return isalpha( (unsigned char )c );

}
```

Comment: error: cannot declare member function 'static bool Tree<t>::aZCheck(char)' to have static linkage [-fpermissive]| 
                Any suggestions?

Comment: @Aistis Taraskevicius You have to use keyword static only with the function declaration within the class.

Comment: Not a single answer has yet explained _why_. For an upvote, explain that taking the address of the function doesn't do what he thinks it does when it's a non-static member.

Answer (score 2):

If your compiler supports C++11 and thus lambdas you could just:

```
  str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), [](char c) { return !isalpha(c); }), str.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

You should provide a free function (outside of class declaration) or a `static` member function for `aZCheck()`.

```
 template<typename t>
 class Tree {
 public:
     static bool aZCheck(char c);
 };
```

and use

```
 str.erase( remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), Tree<t>::aZCheck), str.end());
```

or better simply have a free function

```
 bool aZCheck(char c)  {
     return !isalpha(c));
 }
```

and use

```
 str.erase( remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), aZCheck), str.end());
```

Comment: As a separate question, arent functions outside the class that are needed for class to function would be bad practice? And how would one call a outside class function from the class?

Comment: @AistisTaraskevicius _"aren't functions outside the class ... bad practice .."_ I don't believe they are for this case, It's quite common practice actually.

Comment: @AistisTaraskevicius The even better practice for modern c++ is to use lambda expressions as _@40two_ proposed.